# Red or Rebol: how to convert "test/a" to [test/a]

Tags: rebol, red

I tried to do this:

```
 b: []
 append b  to-word "test/a"
```

but it generates error

> *** Syntax Error: invalid character in: "test/a"
>   *** Where: to
>   *** Stack: run to-word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

;for 30 characters

to block! "test/a"

Answer (score 3):

```
>> append b: copy [] to path! "test/a"
== [test/a]
```

Comment: good answer also but I can only mark one so I took the oldest one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `lit-path!`, but by default the path will be split:

```
>> append [] 'test/a
== [test a]
```

Unless you use the `/only` refinement:

```
>> append/only [] 'test/a
== [test/a]
```

This assumes Red. I'm not sure if it's the same in Rebol.